# Putting an IF statement in SQL query if user has supplied data in that field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a SQL query, where imputs are generated by the user via a search form.  What I have at the moment is this.

```
// Select some data
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `id`, `type_code`, `connector_type`, `construction_type`,  `author`, `estimate_lead_time`, `last_update`, `confidence_level`, `start_passband`, `stop_passband`, `low_passband`, `high_passband` 
                      FROM `filter_bandpass` 
                      WHERE (`start_passband` = $lowfreq AND `stop_passband` = $highfreq)");
```

I'm trying to get it to allow users to only fill out the `$lowfreq` and leave the `$highfreq` blank, and the results will show all results where `$lowfreq =` to user inserted data, but when they do imput an amount for `$highfreq` the result shows both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So either $highfreq contains data or is empty. Then simply replace

```
WHERE (`start_passband` = $lowfreq AND `stop_passband` = $highfreq)");
```

with

```
WHERE (`start_passband` = $lowfreq AND (`stop_passband` = $highfreq OR $highfreq = ''))");
```

Comment: I had a feeling it would be something like that, i had tried that but had missed out a a bracket or something. Thanks a lot! very much appreciated.

Comment: Quick question, that only returns results if i set $highfreq to 0 - is there a way of doing the same but when the form is left blank.

Comment: If I understand correctly, $highfreq gets the string entered in the form. When left blank it should contain ''. This is what my query checks. If the users enters a zero, then $highfreq should contain '0'. I don't know how exactly $highfreq gets replaced by its value in your query. Could be that '' gets replaced by NULL, so you would have to replace `OR $highfreq = ''` with `OR $highfreq is null`. I would have to see more of your code to answer this.